# JavaScript object instantiation options

Tags: javascript

Given:

```
function MyCtor() {}
var myInstance = new MyCtor(); //myInstance.constructor ==== MyCtor

var MyCtor = function() {}
var myInstance = new MyCtor(); //myInstance.constructor ==== Function
```

If you instantiate an object using the former pattern the constructor is "more meaningful".

Is one of these approaches preferred? Are there circumstances where one is more idiomatic?

Comment: The functions will behave identically except for the existence of the non-standard name property in some implementations. Use which ever approach you prefer. It just really doesn't matter.

Comment: ...probably the only technical difference aside from hoisting is that the first should not be inside a block statement since it isn't a statement.

Comment: ...also worth noting that there are dozens of questions on StackOverflow that deal in great detail with the differences between these.

Answer (score 4):

In the first case you have a named function and thus see that name, when you stringify the constructor.

In the second case you just have a pointer to an anonymous function, hence no name can be shown for the constructor.

You can combine both, though, by using a named function for the second case:

```
var MyCtor = function MyCtor() {}
var myInstance = new MyCtor(); //myInstance.constructor === MyCtor
```

this also works:

```
var otherRefName = function MyCtor() {}
var myInstance = new otherRefName(); //myInstance.constructor === MyCtor
```

---

With respect to the usage:

You can use this pattern, when you need to pass around the constructor to some other function (maybe a callback).

A (very very) simplified example could be something like this:

```
getConstructor( type ) {

  switch( type ) {
    case 'a': return function ContrA(){};
    case 'b': return function ContrB(){};
  }

}


var myConstr = getConstructor( 'a' ),
    myInstance = new myContr(); // myInstance.constructor === ConstrA
```

Other related questions:

- [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/q/336859/1169798)

Comment: Understood, but when would you use each? Are there idiomatic usage patterns. Having the constructor property seems to be useful when looking at the objects in memory, assisting debugging.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Wouldn't a new instance instead of the constructor be returned in a factory pattern?

Comment: @Sirko A bit. you return function which you later do `new` on. so we can argue if `new` is missing or not would cause not to call it factory. but  the general idea is that you provide some info about what you want , and something else creates something and return it to you. we later do `new` , so I guess it's pretty close. not to mention that you can't do nothing with `function (){this.x=...}` without `new` it.....:-)

Comment: I wouldn't say that you have a "pointer" to a function since JavaScript doesn't have pointers. The top two examples are held identically as an object reference. And it should be noted that your `===` comparison in the second example will fail because `MyCtor` isn't available in the outer scope. Not sure if you were implying that you could actually make that comparison.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition ( and a bit off)  to @sirko's answer , I will add the hoisting POV :

```
var myInstance = new MyCtor();
function MyCtor() {}
alert(myInstance.constructor ) //MyCtor
```

while

```
var myInstance = new MyCtor();  //error
var MyCtor = function() {}
alert(myInstance.constructor )
```